# Python zip() function not working

Tags: python-3.x, list, zip

I'm new to Stack Overflow and Python.
I am trying to build a word by replacing items in a list by index and when I run this code only the first instance is replace.

```
word = "DRIPPING"
letter = "P"
checkList = [" _ "] * len(word)
letterLocation=[3,4]

for (index, replacement) in zip(letterLocation, letter):
    checkList[index] = replacement

print(checkList)
```

Returns `[' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', 'P', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ']`

Any help will be very welcome.

Comment: `zip` is working perfectly fine, but you use `zip` where you should not use `zip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` takes two or more iterables, and generates tuples that contain an element from each iterable until one of the iterables is exhausted.

Since `letter` contains only one character, `zip` will thus emit only a **single** tuple:

```
>>> list(zip(checkList,letter))
[(' _ ', 'P')]
```

You do not need `zip` here, you can simply iterate over the `checkList`, and assign `letter` to all these indices:

```
for index in letterLocation:  # look ma, no zip
    checkList[index] = letter
```

Comment: Thank you Willem.  You are a star!  Trust me to over complicate things.